# Регулярное выражение для телефонов с пробелами на странице html

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Помогите, пожалуйста, составить регулярное выражение, все перепробовал.
Задача - собрать номера с html страницы в разных вариациях - с пробелами, со скобками и так далее.

Есть выражение, которое собирает все номера

```
preg_match_all('/(\+?(?:(?:\-|\(|\)))?\d){1,31}/is', var_export($html), $results);
```

Однако оно не учитывает пробелы и ковычки. 
Пробовал выражения для обработки

```
/\s|\+|-|\(|\)/
```

Для удаления пробелом и ненужных символов, но много раз погонял и заметил, что они(телефоны с пробелами и кавычками) не попадают в первую выборку.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно объединить поиск телефона на html странице и поиск номеров с пробелами и кавычками? 
Не силен в регулярных выражениях, роюсь в интернете вторые сутки, никак не могу найти решения.

Вот список примеров номеров, которых хотелось бы отыскать

```
8(ddd)ddddddd;
+7(ddd)ddddddd;
+7 ddd ddddddd;
8 ddd ddddddd; (Тут вариации всех пробелов в разных местах например 8 ddd ddd dd dd; и так далее а так же для +7)
8 (ddd ) ddddddd; (Тут вариации всех пробелов в разных местах например 8 (ddd )ddd dd dd; и так далее а так же для +7)
8 (ddd ) ddddddd; (Тут вариации всех пробелов в разных местах например 8 (ddd )ddd dd dd; и так далее а так же для +7)
8 (ddd ) ddddddd; (Тут вариации всех пробелов в разных местах например 8 (ddd )ddd dd dd; и так далее а так же для +7)
8 -ddd - ddd-dd-dd; (Тут вариации всех пробелов и этих самых тире в разных местах например 8 (ddd )ddd dd dd; и так далее а так же для +7)
```

Comment: начните с того, что приведите все варианты, которые вы хотите считать номером телефона

Comment: @splash58, Добавил, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/5CwowW/1 но я не уверен, что не наберет лишнего

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1430837/485997, посмотрите в данном ответе как раз описывается приведение к одному типу телефонных номеров